# How can I have the main process in a Windows Service repeat upon completion

Tags: c#, .net, service

I want to create a Windows .Net service, using c#, that calls a main process in the service's OnStart event and when that main process completes, I want it to run again automatically, until I manually stop the service. The main process can take several hours to complete and the time to complete varies so I don't want to use a timer. Is it as simple as putting the main process in a while loop or should there be some other controlling mechanism?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with putting the code you want to repeat in a loop? It's hard to tell without at least seeing the structure of your code. You just want to make sure OnStart() returns in a timely manner.

Comment: I am curious as to why I got the -3 down vote. If someone could post a comment explaining, I can avoid doing,  whatever I did wrong in the question, in the future. thx

Answer (score 1):

Building on what @itsme86 said in his comment, in my service  OnStart methods, I added a thread and assigned it a method in my code, as follows;

```
    private bool m_isRunning = false;
    Thread m_thread;

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            m_thread = new Thread(StartService);
            m_thread.Start();
            m_isRunning = true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (m_logger != null)
            {
                m_logger.Error(ex, "An exception has occurred in the OnStart method call");
            }
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

In my OnStop method, I added the following code;

```
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {
            m_isRunning = false;
            m_logger.Information("Application stopped.");
            m_thread = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (m_logger != null)
            {
                m_logger.Error(ex, "An exception has occurred in the OnStop method call");
            }
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Then I set up the loop in the StartService method, as shown below;

```
    private void StartService()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeLogger();
            m_logger.Information("Application started.");
            while (m_isRunning)
            {
                RunProcess();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (m_logger != null)
            {
                m_logger.Error(ex, "An exception has occurred in the StartService method call");
            }
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The RunProcess method performs the service duties and when it completes, it fires again due to the while loop in the StartService method.

This all seems to work as I had wanted.